# java.lang.nullpointerexception error

Tags: java, netbeans, jsp, servlets, glassfish

a ver si me podrian ayudar por que no encuentro el error.
al introducirle el for al jsp deja de funcionar. Antes de agregar el for la pagina funciona.
la consola de NetBeans me dice que el error esta en la linea 30 (donde esta el getRequestDispatcher)
Antes que nada aclaro que tengo todas las importaciones correctas y en un proyecto de prueba comprobe que la consulta se realiza con exito.
Por lo que entiendo el error java.lang.nullpointerexception significa que me falta un objeto. El problema es que no logro encontrar que es lo que esta vacio. Mi teoria es que el array esta vacio (basicamente por que es el unico objeto que uso ), pero los comic estan agregados, asi que no se.

EDIT:
probe poner un for que imprima del uno al 5 para ver si el problema estaba al mandarle codigo java y resulta que el jsp sigue funcionando. el problema efectivamente esta cuando llamo al ArrayList, pero estoy seguro de que no esta vacio.

codigo del servlet:

```
protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
                        throws ServletException, IOException {

                        request.getRequestDispatcher("listacomics.jsp").forward(request, response);

                    try{

                                        ConnectionManager connectionManager = new ConnectionManager();
                                         Connection con = connectionManager.getConnection();
                                            Statement stm;
                                            ResultSet rs;
                                            String sql;

                                            sql = "SELECT * FROM comic, categorias, autor, estados, users WHERE com_cat_id = cat_id AND com_est_id = est_id AND com_autor_id = autor_id AND com_user_id = user_id";

                                            stm = con.createStatement();
                                            rs = stm.executeQuery(sql);

                                            ArrayList<Comic> listaComics = new ArrayList<>();

                                            while(rs.next()){
                                                Comic comic = new Comic();

                                                comic.setComicTitulo(rs.getString("com_titulo"));

                                                Categoria categoria = new Categoria();
                                                categoria.setCatID(rs.getInt("cat_id"));
                                                categoria.setCatNombre(rs.getString("cat_nombre"));
                                                comic.setComicCategoria(categoria);

                                                Autor autor = new Autor();
                                                autor.setAutorId(rs.getInt("autor_id"));
                                                autor.setAutorNombre(rs.getString("autor_nombre"));
                                                comic.setComicAutor(autor);

                                                Estado estado = new Estado();
                                                estado.setEstadoId(rs.getInt("est_id"));
                                                estado.setEstadoNombre(rs.getString("est_nombre"));
                                                comic.setComicEstado(estado);

                                                User usuario = new User();
                                                usuario.setUserId(rs.getInt("user_id"));
                                                usuario.setUserName(rs.getString("username"));
                                                usuario.setUserPass(rs.getString("user_pass"));
                                                usuario.setUserNombre(rs.getString("user_nombre"));
                                                usuario.setUserEmail(rs.getString("user_email"));
                                                usuario.setUserFoto(rs.getString("user_foto"));
                                                usuario.setUserDescripcion(rs.getString("user_desc"));
                                                comic.setComicUser(usuario);

                                                comic.setComicDescripcion(rs.getString("com_descripcion"));
                                                comic.setComicFecha(rs.getDate("com_fecha"));
                                                comic.setComicFoto(rs.getString("com_tapa"));
                                                comic.setComicId(rs.getInt("com_id"));






                                                listaComics.add(comic);


                                            }

                                            request.setAttribute("listaComics", listaComics); 

                                            stm.close();
                                            rs.close();



                                    }catch (SQLException ex) {
                                        System.out.println("Error al obtener el listado de comics");
                                    }

                                }
```

codigo del JSP

```
            <%@page import="java.util.ArrayList"%>
            <%@page import="com.mycompany.webcomics.entities.Comic"%>
            <%@page contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
            <%  ArrayList<Comic> listaComic = (ArrayList<Comic>) request.getAttribute("listaComics"); %>
            <!DOCTYPE html>
            <html>
                <head>
                    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
                    <title>JSP Page</title>
                </head>
                <body>
                    <h1>Hello World!papa</h1>

                    <select>
                        <% for( Comic unComic: listaComic){ %>

                        <option value=" <%= unComic.getComicId() %> "> <%= unComic.getComicTitulo()%> </option>
                        <%
                            }
                           %>
                    </select>

                </body>
            </html>
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Como estás desplegando a un servidor te recomiendo usar un logger en vez de tus souts, ya que a veces no se renderizan en tu log de errores.

Answer (score 0):

Puedes ser que estas mostrando el jsp antes de poner el atributo

```
request.getRequestDispatcher("listacomics.jsp").forward(request, response);           
 try{
.....
}catch (SQLException ex) {
 System.out.println("Error al obtener el listado de comics");
}
```

Comment: hola, disculpen, ya me habia percatado y no edite el post. de igual manera el jsp sigue sin funcionar

Comment: @GermanBaldi estas redirigiendo al jsp antes del try? `  request.getRequestDispatcher("listacomics.jsp").forward(request, response);`